# Ajax HTTP error occured. HTTP Result code: 200

Tags: views, ajax, paging

I get Ajax error when I click next button. You can test it [here](http://etraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/events_page).

I have found out the problem. It is due to the custom module which I have made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 *
 * This hook declares what blocks are provided by the module.
 */
function custom_module_block_info()
{
    $blocks['tag_cloud'] = array(
        // The name that will appear in the block list.
        'info' => t('Custom Moudle'),
        // Default setting.
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE
    );
    return $blocks;
}
```

When I remove the first two line (Doctype and meta). It works fine. But If I remove first two lines. It doesn't work on IE. I had to insert these two statements to get it working on IE. Now If I keep these two lines, it causes Ajax error, and if not It doesn't work on IE.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably an echo in your code is creating the problem. Please check if there is any unnecessary echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add arbitrary HTML at the top of a module file - Drupal runs through a process to theme the page, and you need hook into that.

You have a couple of options:

1. Override [html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7) in your theme, and add the tag to the `<head>` section manually. This is probably the easiest way.
2. Use [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) in your module, e.g.

   ```
   $tag = $element = array(
     '#tag' => 'meta', 
     '#attributes' => array(
       'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible',
       'content' => 'IE=edge',
     ),
   );
   drupal_add_html_head($tag, 'mymodule:ua_compatibility');
   ```

Make sure you pick an appropriate hook to do this in (`preprocess_page`, etc), don't just add it to the top of the file or it won't work.